# Not geting value while Parsing Json String in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, json.net, deserialization

I am getting the json string "jasonContent" from nyTimes. When I write the following code I can get the values of total and offset but i am interested in results,but I am getting nothing for results.The string I am receiving is something like this

```
{

  "offset": "0",

   "results": [

    {
      "body": " news goes here",

      "byline": "By SANA SIWOLOP",
      "date": "20110511",
      "title": "SQUARE FEET; Chelsea Piers, a Manhattan Sports Center, Expands Close to Home",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/2011\/05\/11\/realestate\/commercial\/chelsea-piers-a-manhattan-sports-center-expands-close-to-home.html"
    },
    {
      "body": "news 2 goes here",
      "byline": "By ROB HUGHES",
      "date": "20110511",
      "title": "ON SOCCER; Racial Politics Rear Their Head in French Soccer",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/2011\/05\/11\/sports\/soccer\/11iht-SOCCER11.html"
    },
    {
      "body": "news3 does here",
      "byline": "By RICHARD SANDOMIR",
      "date": "20110511",
      "title": "Gus Johnson Joins Fox Sports",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.nytimes.com\/2011\/05\/11\/sports\/gus-johnson-joins-fox-sports.html"
    },],"tokens": [
 "sports" ],
  "total": 152539
}
```

For parsing this string I am writing the following code

```
 public class nytimesnews
{
    public string offset { get; set; }
    public resultobject news2;
    public string total { get; set; }
}

public class resultobject
{
    public results[] news;
}

public class results
{
    public string body { get; set; }
    public string byline { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}


nytimesnews parse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<nytimesnews>(jasonContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. (I was using Json.NET). I noticed that the variables of the nytimesnews class should be named according to the json string. I made following changes to the code and it worked perfectly.

```
 public class nytimesnews
 {
       // name of these variables are just like the  data tags in json string
       public string offset { get; set; }      
       public result[] results;
       public string total { get; set; }
 }

 public class results
 {
       public string body { get; set; }
       public string byline { get; set; }
       public string date { get; set; }
       public string title { get; set; }
       public string url { get; set; }
 }
```

Then in my main class I just used following code

```
 // jasonContent is the jason string
 nytimesnews parse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<nytimesnews>(jasonContent);
 jasonContent = parse.results[1].body;
```